# how to use switch-case with handleMessage interface

Tags: android, handler, android-handler

I want to know how to use switch-case when using handleMessage interface. as shown below in the code, in the run() method I am sending different messages while 
I have only one handler with handleMessage() interface, I want to know how to use switch-case to handle different messages sent

**in onCreate**:

```
private void initObjs() {
    Log.w(TAG, CSubTag.bullet("initObjs"));

    this.mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        ..
        ..
        }
    };
}
```

**in run()**:

```
public void run() {

        //initiating connection
        BluetoothSocket rfcSocket = mSPPCtrl.rfcConnect();
        if (rfcSocket.isConnected()) {
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("CONNECTED", "RFC-SOCKET CONNECTED");
            msg.setData(b);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            //assigning stream variables
            try {
                this.mRFCOS = rfcSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                this.mRFCIS = rfcSocket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("DISCONNECTED", "RFC-SOCKET NOT CONNECTED");
            msg.setData(b);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. before sendMessage(msg),give msg.what a int value,like 0,1,2...
2. in handleMessage(),use swith case;

Comment: would u please clarify with a sample code??because i do not know how to assign to msg.what a value

Comment: {
 Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
 if (rfcSocket.isConnected()) {
        b.putString("CONNECTED", "RFC-SOCKET CONNECTED");
        msg.what = 0;
    } else { 
        b.putString("DISCONNECTED", "RFC-SOCKET NOT CONNECTED");
        msg.what = 1;
    }
 msg.setData(b);
 mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

Answer (score 0):

Define message constants like

```
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 1;
public static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 2;
```

Handler :

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch(msg.what) {
        case STATE_CONNECTED:
          //do your stuff
          break;
        case STATE_DISCONNECTED:
           //do your stuff
           break;
        default : 
           //default condition
           break;
    }
}
```

And in run()

```
public void run() {
        ...
        if (rfcSocket.isConnected()) {
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(STATE_CONNECTED);
            ...

        } else {
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(STATE_DISCONNECTED);
            ...
        }
}
```

Comment: how msg.what got assigned to value 1 or 2

Comment: pass it in obtainMessage()